# "Woman front bits" meaning

Tags: meaning, transatlantic-differences, insular-english

Whats does "woman front bits" actually means?

This question is surprisingly inspired by one of the answers 
to [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/is-there-any-united-states-slang-i-should-avoid-in-the-uk-or-ireland) question: "Is there any slang I should avoid in the UK or Ireland".
It is appropriate to quote it here:

> Avoid the use of the word "fanny", as it is slang for, ah, a woman's
>   front bits. Be very careful when referring to your fanny pack!

In dictionary I have it is written that "fanny" indeed is a British English pejorative term for female genitalia.  On the other hand, in urban dictionary we can [read about](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=front%20bits) two different meanings of "front bits" term:

- The male private parts.
- the way a Brit explains breasts.

So, not that it is the most important slang word in my life, but what does this term exactly mean talking of women.

Comment: In the US, *fanny* is a euphemism for *buttocks*.  I can't wrap my mind around bringing *fanny* round to the front.  :)

Comment: I think it's the front side of labia majora, aka "cameltoe".

Comment: As the *"ah"* in OP's citation implies, the writer is being exceptionally delicate/prissy. The standard form of the euphemism (always somewhat facetious/jocular) is *"front **bottom**"*.

Comment: @cornbread ninja: We Brits always have to wrap our minds around your "damned Yankee" usage. If a lady with an American accent says *"My fanny is sore"* we understand what she means without getting all worked up about it. If a lady with a British accent says it (in mixed company) we probably assume she's not really a "lady" at all (she's most likely a drunken slag! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We understand what she means *now*, thanks to this question. It never occurred to me that the US usage would be different to UK use.

Comment: Strange this is the 10th word I know about females private parts in English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and now I'll know too, and knowing is half the battle!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the UK, certainly, a fanny is slang for vagina.

A lady's front bits would definitely mean vagina and not breasts.  A less-oft-used term is "front bum" which is also slang for vagina.

I have never known front bits refer to breasts.

Comment: In the US, *front bum* (butt, as we call it) refers to the unfortunate circumstance of being heavy enough to have a sub-navel, frontal protrusion resembling buttocks.

Comment: well it is actually the vulva, urethra and vagina, but that is being really picky

Answer (score 4):

In British English *fanny* means a woman's genitals, and the NOAD adds also that it means a person's buttocks. Actually, the NOAD reports first "a person's buttocks," and then the British meaning.

The *Shorter Oxford English Dictionary* says that *bits* means a person's genitals, or a woman's breasts. The same dictionary says that *fanny* means the female genitals, or the buttocks (in North American); it also adds the word can be used in combination with other words, such as in *fanny belt*, or *fanny pack*.